# Taking Longer time to get LastModified Date VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below code to get the last modified datetime of a file from a shared folder.

```
Public Sub CountTextFilesInFolder()
FolderPath = "\\SVTickets\"
Count = 0
If Right(FolderPath, 1) = "\" Then
    SourcePath = FolderPath
    SourcPath = SourcePath & "*.txt"
ElseIf Right(FolderPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    SourcePath = FolderPath
    SourcPath = SourcePath & "*.txt"
End If

FileName = Dir(SourcPath)
Do While FileName <> ""
    DateTim = FileDateTime(SourcePath & FileName)
    If Format(DateTim, "YYYYMMDD") = Format(Date, "YYYYMMDD") Then
        Count = Count + 1
    End If
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Could someone suggest how can be improved the performance of the above code.
There are 7k files inside that folder and taking hours to run.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Where is the share located?

Comment: Try [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6tkce7xa(v=vs.84).aspx), need manual search for the file extensions though. Would love to see performance difference.

Comment: Shared folder located on a Server

Comment: I tried with FileSystemObject and there is not much difference, it took same time as above

Comment: Sounds like it's a bottleneck on the switch/server/NAS. Has anyone tried to run the code on a server with direct access?

Comment: if i use my local path, this code run fast and if we are accessing directly and it takes longer time

Answer (score 0):

Command line? The following writes out the details to the immediate window.
`C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestFolder` is the folder to loop over which you can extract out into a variable. If there are a lot of files you wouldn't debug.print but could write array direct out to sheet.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Find_Files()

    Dim fileDetails() As String
    fileDetails = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\TestFolder && for /f %a in ('dir /b *.txt') do @echo %a %~ta").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(fileDetails) To UBound(fileDetails)
        If Not IsEmpty(fileDetails(i)) Then Debug.Print fileDetails(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Messy version for network drive:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Find_Files()
    Dim folderpath As String
    Dim drive As String
    folderpath = "\Folder1\Folder2\TestFolder"
    drive = "R:"
    Dim fileDetails() As String
    fileDetails = Split(CreateObject("wscript.shell").exec("cmd /c cd /D " & drive & " && cd " & folderpath & " && for /f %a in ('dir /b *.txt') do @echo %a %~ta").stdout.readall, vbCrLf)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(fileDetails) To UBound(fileDetails)
        If Not IsEmpty(fileDetails(i)) Then Debug.Print fileDetails(i)
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: How can i use this code
for /f %a in ('dir /b *.txt') do @echo %a %~ta > "C:\ChangeThisAsRequiredTToOutputPath\fileinfo.txt"

Comment: You would do Windows key + R to open run window then type cmd and press enter

Comment: Then in the box that opens you would type cd "enter directory path of desired folder"

Comment: press enter, then enter the above but change "C:\ChangeThisAsRequiredTToOutputPath\fileinfo.txt" to the full path of the file you want to create, then press enter....It will create the file at that destination with the information inside.

Comment: shall i use it through VBA

Comment: No VBA required. It as per instructions above. You could execute it via Shell in vba or even a bat file but seems much simpler to just do it direct via cmd (command prompt)

Comment: Did it make sense in the end?

Comment: Actually i am looking for a dynamic execution instead of doing manual steps. as i have to check multiple Shared folders.

Comment: i tried this command for /f %a in ('dir /b *.txt') do @echo %a %~ta > "C:\ChangeThisAsRequiredTToOutputPath\fileinfo.txt"
and it is giving only one file details in text file. i am expecting all the .txt file details in that file

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, it is working for local folder..
how can i use mapped network drive.. i tried to change it to NetWorkDrive name Like Z:\ instead of C:\, it is not working

Any suggestion how to change it.

Comment: Bit of a messy version loaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response and the code is working as expecting. but time of execution is high.

Comment: Worse than before or better? Bearing in mind I assume you have optimized this with switching off ScreenUpdating etc all the usual suspects and dumping out in one go to the sheet?

Comment: not much difference and it is taking time while executing the Command on CMD to get the data into array.

Comment: so not helpful at all ? :-(

Comment: the two codes are executing more or less at same time.
Thanks a Ton for your effort and the guidance provided.